# override eclipse property view

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface, treeviewer

I really need a help. I am struck here. I wanted to override eclipse property view and show my properties for each nodes in the swt `Tree`. To be clear I am not using JFace `TreeViewer`. I implemented my entire project in using SWT `Tree`. I seen lots of exampls while gooling using `TreeViewer`. I tried to convert the `Tree` to `TreeViewer`, but the all the nodes at root level are shown up but thier childers are not seen. Can I overirde the property view using Tree? If not then how to resolve the `TreeViewer` problem I mentioned above?
Thanks Tor

Comment: There seem to be a number of questions in here. Can you start with one, and perhaps post the code you are using in TreeViewer so that we can help answer the question about converting the Tree to TreeViewer. You almost certainly should use the TreeViewer rather than Tree.